# webpack-stream: где указать настройки при использовании другой версии webpack

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack, webpack2, webpack-stream

В [документации](https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream) `webpack-stream` заявлена возможность использовать не ту версию `webpack`, которая является зависимостью `webpack-stream`, а ту, которая установлена отдельно:

> If you would like to use a different version of webpack than the one
>   this plugin uses, pass in an optional 2nd argument:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var gulpWebpack = require('webpack-stream');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/entry.js')
    .pipe(gulpWebpack({}, webpack))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Это привлекательно в первую очередь тем, что можно использовать последнию версию `webpack 2.x.x`, а не deprecated-зависимость `1.x.x`. Но где нужно прописывать настройки `webpack` в данном случае? Для случаев, когда используется зависимость, примеры настроек в документации есть (например, указание внешнего файла конфигурации или нескольких точек входа), но для внешней версии `webpack` не сказано, как прописывать настройки.

Я пробовал вариант с настройками во внешнем файле. Если мы создадим `webpack.config.js`-файл, то он будет проигнорирован. Webpack отработает без ошибок компиляции, но сгенерирует файл с именем вроде `ba2e257fdec0945b554e.js` при следующих настройках в `gulp`-файле:

```
var  gulp = require('gulp'), 
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');

gulp.task('wpstream', function() {
  return gulp.src('development/03_es6/index.js')
    .pipe(webpackStream({}, webpack))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('development/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})); 
});
```

Насколько я могу сделать вывод, запуск консольной комманды `gulp wpstream` не приведёт к тому же результату, что и выполнение комманды `webpack`. В последнем случае всё отрабатывает корректно с учётом инструкций `webpack.config.js`, хотя в обоих случах выполняется та желаемая (новая) версия `webpack`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

когда ты конфигурируешь задачу следующим образом:

```
gulp.task('wpstream', function() {
  return gulp.src('development/03_es6/index.js')
    .pipe(webpackStream({}, webpack))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('development/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})); 
});
```

В `webpackStream({}, webpack)` ты передаешь 2 параметра:
1 - объект конфигурации
2 - движок вебпака, который будет все обрабатывать.
есть еще 3-й параметр - фукция для ручной обработки и вывода статистики и ошибок.
Тебе же нужно обратить внимание на первый агрумент который ты передаешь, а это пустой объект.
Если заглянуть в исходники `webpack-sream`, то можно увидеть, что если настройки не передаются или передается пустой объект, то `webpack-sream` запускает сам вебпак со своими дефолтными настройками.
Поэтому существует как минимум 2 способа передать настройки:
1 - опрелить их прямо в `webpackStream({здесь настройки}, webpack)`
2- взять настройки из файла `webpack.condig.js`

Во втором случае задача будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
var  gulp = require('gulp'), 
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    webpackStream = require('webpack-stream'),
    webpackconfig = requre(./webpack.config.js);

gulp.task('wpstream', function() {
  return gulp.src('development/03_es6/index.js')
    .pipe(webpackStream(webpackconfig, webpack))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('development/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})); 
});
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!